# JQuery Beginner .after is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the problem with the code? I'm sure that path of js file is correct. I think it's the code. It is not showing the inserted paragraph..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Embedded Script</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Embedded Script Example</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("h1").after("<p>I've just inserted a paragraph</p>");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Do you have an h1 in your html?

Comment: @NicolásTorres. No... he doesn't not, see his HTML...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the path is not correct. The rest looks just fine to me.

Comment: this should work fine, check the console for errors, probably jQuery isn't inserted correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You path must be wrong, or your jQuery library is somehow corrupt.  I have copied your code, changed the jQuery path to the most recent code on jquery.com, and uploaded the page to http://www.apsillers.com/inline.html. Use `Ctrl+U` to view the source to verify that it is the same as yours.  (I would use a fiddle but it doesn't allow inline scripts, I think.)

This proves pretty conclusively that your problem is due to a failure to properly load the jQuery library. Check your error console, and verify that `jQuery` is an extant object in your JS console.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("<p>I've just inserted a paragraph</p>").insertAfter("h1");
```

Comment: This is identical to what the OP already has. `insertAfter` works in exactly the same way as `after`. The only difference is that with `after`, the element(s) to insert are passed to the method.